# Unignore vendor folder for deployment

Tags: symfony, composer-php, openshift, web-deployment

I have been trying to deploy my Symfony2 project in Openshift with 1 small gear.  My plan was to execute `composer update` once I finish pushing my codes into the server.  Unfortunately an error keeps telling me that there is not enough memory to execute the command.

So I thought of unignoring the bundles that I needed in the vendor folder by removing them from the `.gitignore` file but still it doesn't get included in the commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is known to consume a lot of memory. You should build you're project (`composer update`, `php app/console assetic:dump`, ...) and then push it to the server. Take a look at Jenkins, it's great tool.

Anyway if you want to force tracking of ignored files you can use the `git add -f` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should only update composer in dev, for the prod server use: composer install (you need to have composer.lock under version control)

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem connected with insufficient memory on the server. The solution is to add swap partition, so that you have enough memory to complete the update.

```
free -m
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024 // 1GB, or
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=2048 // 2GB
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Once you have added the swap you may run the update command, and it will complete successfully